# OpenCV output to MJPEG stream

Tags: opencv, mjpeg

My application uses CvCapture to gather the image and uses Matrices to perform the processing. The program currently runs headless. How do I write a Matrix to an JPEG stream so I can stream it over HTTP?

Can I put the MJPEG stream in nGinX WWW root and serve it through there or do I need to use a specific streaming application?